# Entity Framework Code First. What is the good approach entities design with the same properies?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I design entities for my business model, and I think how optimally write their. The entities are items for combo box control, and user will be choose item. User can edit the list items. Over time,  there are too many similar entities with the same properties.

However, I try describe abstract class for their entities, but I am not confident what is good.

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class ItemEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class TaxSystem : ItemEntity
{
}

public class RentType : ItemEntity
{
}

...
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this implementation. Another option (if you guarantee that they will always have the same property) is that you use only one entity (one class) and add an additional `enum` property to indicate the "type" of the "item".

Comment: Voted to close, because 'opinion based': There is really no optimal way. It depends on what you are trying to achieve. A hint: I use the `MapInheritedProperties()` method of [EntityMappingConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.entitymappingconfiguration-1?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) for my use case.